# how to integrate pushwoosh in lower version?

Tags: android, push-notification, pushwoosh

I am trying to use pushwoosh in my android native app for push notifications.It is working fine in higher versions.My application's min sdk version is 8. Is there any compatibility problem for android lower versions(from 8 to 11)?I tried both pushwoosh.jar and pushwoosh sdk for this.But both are not working in lower versions.What I should do to get push notifications in lower versions also?

Answer (score 0):

From the PushWhoosh site...

"Due to compatibility with Android 4 please make sure you are using at least 11 version of the Android API."

See...

http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android/native-android-sdk-integration/

Answer (score 0):

The SDK will work correctly with the lower API. But in order to compile you need to set at least 11 version of the Android API.

If you don't receive push notifications on version 8 to 11, let me know!

Comment: Pushwoosh is not working in lower versions after sdk usage and compilation with higher version.Is there anything else to check?do you have any suggestions?